# How to do partial inheritance in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I have a class, `Bond`, which has as instances a term that we’ll invest in them, a certain amount that will be invested, a minimum price, a minimum term and yearly interest rate. The subclass `LongTerm` has minimum term of 2  years, a minimum amount of $250 and a yearly interest of 2.5%.

The following code works correctly:

```
class Bond(object):
    def __init__(self,minTerm, term,amount,minPrice,yrlyRate):
        self.term = term
        self.amount = amount
        self.minPrice = minPrice
        self.minTerm = minTerm
        self.yrlyRate = yrlyRate

class LongTerm(Bond):
    def __init__(self, term,amount,minPrice, minAmount = 1000, minTerm = 5, yrlyRate = 0.05):
        self.term = term
        self.amount = amount
        self.minPrice = minPrice
        self.minAmount = minAmount
        self.minTerm = minTerm
        self.yrlyRate = yrlyRate
```

But when I use the partial inheritance function

```
super().__init__(term,amount,minPrice)
```

it shows an error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'minPrice' and 'yrlyRate'
```

Code using `super()`:

```
class Bond(object):
    def __init__(self,minTerm, term,amount,minPrice,yrlyRate):
        self.term = term
        self.amount = amount
        self.minPrice = minPrice
        self.minTerm = minTerm
        self.yrlyRate = yrlyRate

class LongTerm(Bond):
    def __init__(self, term,amount,minPrice, minAmount = 1000, minTerm = 5, yrlyRate = 0.05):
        super().__init__(term,amount,minPrice)
        self.term = term
        self.amount = amount
        self.minPrice = minPrice
```

Why should not I be able to partially inherit only some instances of the superclass?

Comment: btw you don't need to inherit from `object`, that was necessary only in Python2.x or sth like that, basically it should be just `class Bond:`

Comment: If you inherit from Bond, then you are binding yourself to the contract established by its ‘init()’ method. You should stick to that contract or perhaps you don’t want the inheritance.

Comment: So I cannot do partial inheritance? I should write the instances all over again as I did in the first bunch of code?

Comment: @Foucault you could restructure the first class to do sth like `def __init__(*args)` and then only if `len(args)` is greater than something assign the rest of the values? or use default values, either how you don't need partial inheritance, you are still using all the arguments in the child class as you do in the parent class and then some and those additional arguments are the ones you assign in the child class

Comment: There's no such thing as "partial inheritance", it's all or nothing. See [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your subclass requires less information than your superclass, then perhaps you don't need to use inheritance. In the event that it's not possible to modify the original class then perhaps composition would be more helpful.

### Method 1. With general class inheritance

```
class Bond:
    def __init__(self, minTerm, term, amount, minPrice, yrlyRate):
        self.term = term
        self.amount = amount
        self.minPrice = minPrice
        self.minTerm = minTerm
        self.yrlyRate = yrlyRate


class LongTerm(Bond):
    def __init__(self, term, amount, minPrice, minAmount = 1000, minTerm = 5, yrlyRate = 0.05):
        super().__init__(minTerm, term, amount, minPrice, yrlyRate)
        self.minAmount = minAmount
```

### Method 2. With overriding example and defaulting arguments

```
class Bond:
    def __init__(self, minTerm, term, amount, minPrice, yrlyRate):
        self.term = term
        self.amount = amount
        self.minPrice = minPrice
        self.minTerm = minTerm
        self.yrlyRate = yrlyRate
    
    def short_term_only(self):
        #do some stuff

        
class LongTerm(Bond):
    def __init__(self, term, amount, minPrice, minAmount = 1000, minTerm = 5, yrlyRate = 0.05):
        # In the event that maybe we don't care about some of the information or methods
        # in the parent we can set them to none or even over-ride the methods
        super().__init__(minTerm, None, None, minPrice, yrlyRate)
        self.minAmount = minAmount
        
    def short_term_only(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

### Method 3. With class composition

The concern with this method is that methods available to class `Bond` won't be inherently available to class `LongTerm`:

```
class LongTerm:
    def __init__(self, term, amount, minPrice, minAmount = 1000, minTerm = 5, yrlyRate = 0.05):
        self.bond = Bond(minTerm, term, amount, minPrice, yrlyRate)
        self.minAmount = minAmount
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is something like this...

```
class Bond:
    def __init__(self, term, amount, minPrice, minTerm, yrlyRate):
        self.term = term
        self.amount = amount
        self.minPrice = minPrice
        self.minTerm = minTerm
        self.yrlyRate = yrlyRate

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Term: {self.term}, Amount: {self.amount}, MinPrice: {self.minPrice}, MinTerm: {self.minTerm}, YearlyRate: {self.yrlyRate}"

class LongTerm(Bond):
    def __init__(self, term, amount, minPrice, minTerm=5, yrlyRate=0.05, minAmount=1000):
        super().__init__(term=term, amount=amount, minPrice=minPrice, minTerm=minTerm, yrlyRate=yrlyRate)
        self.minAmount = minAmount

print(LongTerm(term=1, amount=23, minPrice=45.2))
```